# Ruby-style string interpolation in AppleScript

Tags: ruby, applescript

Is there a way to achieve Ruby-style, string interpolation in AppleScript?  I need a flexible way of creating string patterns.

Ruby:

```
fn = "john"
=> "john"

ln = "doe"
=> "doe"

addresses = []
=> []

addresses << "#{fn[0]}#{ln}@company.com"
=> ["jdoe@company.com"]

addresses << "#{fn}.#{ln}@company.com"
=> ["jdoe@company.com", "john.doe@company.com"]
```

AppleScript:

```
set fn to "john"
set ln to "doe"

set theAddresses to {}

# jdoe@company.com
copy [something here] & "@company.com" to the end of theAddresses
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there's no string interpolation in AppleScript. The equivalent would be something like this:

```
copy first character of fn & ln & "@company.com" to the end of theAddresses
copy fn & "." & ln & "@company.com" to the end of theAddresses

# {"jdoe@company.com", "john.doe@company.com"}
```

Comment: This is really sad. Almost all other languages start to support string interpolation. Apple simply stopped developing AppleScript.

Comment: @FranklinYu yes, they keep limiting users more and more. macOS has become a very controlled environment.